# a newbie and thought I had a decent understanding of R, but

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been programming in R for about 4/6 months and I thought I had a decent understanding of R but after today (and many hours on the web without being able to find the solution to my problems) I feel like dog poop. :(

Within a function, I just want to add 2 columns in a data frame.

I realize that this seems very simple to many of you but I have spent hours online trying to find the answer with no luck as to why my code is wrong.

My dataframe is:

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(V1=1:10,V2=11:20,V3=21:30,V4=31:40);
```

At first I tried the following function:

```
y <- function(data,a,b){
 V5 <- data$a + data$b;
 print(V5); # this just prints "numeric(0)"
 return(data); # dataframe2 is the same as dataframe1
}

dataframe2 <- y(dataframe1,V1,V2); # as stated above, dataframe2 is the same as dataframe1
```

The above did not work.

I found a post with a question like mine and the suggestion was to use "[row,colum]" formatting as opposed to "$" so I tried (dataframe1 is as above):

```
y <- function(data,a,b){
 V5 <- data[,a] + data[,b];
 print(V5); # this actually prints "a+b" but not into the data frame, but..
 return(data); # as before, dataframe2 is the same as dataframe1
}

dataframe2 <- y(data=dataframe1,a="V1",b="V2"); # as before, dataframe2 is the same as dataframe1
```

This time around "V5" did print but did not show up in dataframe2.

What is wrong with my syntax? I want to dataframe2 to have column "V5" which is just the addition of V1 and V2.

I realize that for many of you this is very simple but I have tried many lines of code and have searched the web for hours with no luck.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Dan

PS: My first post so I hope the formatting is correct and that it ends up in the right forum.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be on the right track. Your function is indeed creating the V5 column that you want to place into your data frame, but you do not return an updated data frame. Notice that your function does not actually ever place that calculated column into the frame that is returned from the function.

A small change within the function should create the behavior you are expecting.

```
y <- function(data,a,b){
 V5 <- data[,a] + data[,b];
 print(V5); # this actually prints "a+b" but not into the data frame, but..
 updatedframe <- data;
 updatedframe$V5 <- V5;
 return(updatedframe); # as before, dataframe2 is the same as dataframe1
}

dataframe2 <- y(data=dataframe1,a="V1",b="V2"); # as before, dataframe2 is the same as dataframe1
```

In this updated form of the function, we create a copy of the existing data frame, named `updatedframe`. Then we assign the V5 column of the `updatedframe` to contain the values calculated in the first step of the function, by using `updatedframe$V5 <- V5`. Finally, we return the copied data frame with the added column.

[Here is a reference for information about adding columns to a data frame.](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Adding_and_removing_columns_from_a_data_frame/)